# Extension Update behavior when Upgrading from Opera 12 to Opera 15

Tags: opera-extension

my question is about the update behavior when updating Opera 12 to Opera 15 from the extensions.

When you have a Opera 12 Extension installed from the Add-on Website, after updating to Opera 15, will then the corresponding Opera 15 extension be installed/updated?

When yes, are the locally saved data be transfered to the new extension? (local storage, web sql database)

I'm asking as a developer who's extension in Opera 12 saves lot of data in a web sql database and wants to make the update to the new Opera as painless as possible for the extension user. (Without loosing these data).

Greetings,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upon upgrading, the corresponding Opera 15 extension (if made available by the extension author) will be installed.

However, locally saved data will not be transfered to the O15 extension.

It is probably best to offer the user an export/import option, sot that he can manually move his data between the two extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one follow up: Is the installation of the corresponding Opera 15 extension an "install" or an "update"? (The 'reason': see http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/runtime.html#event-onInstalled)